# Get Web Api consumer IP Address and HostName in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have hosted Web Api developed in ASP.net. I want if someone call my API so I can log in database so later on if I want to reject request from particular id using C#.

What is best practice to get consumer IP and HostName?

```
public static string GetIP4Address()
  {
    string IP4Address = String.Empty;

    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString())))
    {
      if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
      {
        IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
        break;
      }
    }

    if (IP4Address != String.Empty)
    {
      return IP4Address;
    }

    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
      if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
      {
        IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
        break;
      }
    }

    return IP4Address;
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Resolving names sounds like a bad idea. What if you are called from a client machine that dns doesn't resolve? I tell you, dns takes forever and then fails with an exception you have to catch and log as "unknown host name".

As for request address, just get it with

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Comment: @SOFUser - HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName`

Comment: @SOFUser - And if you read the comments in that very old article, you will see that the header he was looking at can easily be faked and that is not a recommended approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726576/system-web-httpcontext-current-request-userhostaddress