# How to get IpAddress and UserAgent in ASP.NET Web API get methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Web Api to expose a few GET methods.

But before I return the data I need to log a couple of details to the db, of which few of them are as listed below :

- Caller's Ip
- Caller's User Agent
- Caller's Used Url

Now in the controller when I used to do this I used to use the following code,

```
var ipAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
var userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
```

But here in Web API I am unable to use this.

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
public static LogModel GetApiLogDetails()
{
    var logModel = new LogModel();
    logModel.TimeStamp   = DateTime.Now;
    logModel.CallerIp    = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    logModel.CallerAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
    logModel.CalledUrl   = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
    return logModel;
}
```

with a little help from

[Get Web Api consumer IP Address and HostName in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712720/get-web-api-consumer-ip-address-and-hostname-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
&

[Get the IP address of the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host)

Comment: I would try and avoid HttpContext as it only works in WebHost.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: Since this question has come up many times, do you think Web API should have an extension on HttpRequestMessage to get the client IP address? Like the System.Web.Http.WebHost and System.Web.Http.Owin.Selfhost can create request message extensions which users could use.

Comment: @KiranChalla  It would be a fairly low impact change that would definitely help a lot of people.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: Sure, created an issue here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1116

Comment: How-to add System.Web to NET 6 Minimal API ? good pattern ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `HttpRequestMessage` class, that conteins all data you need.

Read more:

- [How to get IP adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host)
- [Extension methods for HttpRequestMessage](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Apr/15/WebAPI-Getting-Headers-QueryString-and-Cookie-Values)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.aspx)

Comment: How-to use HttpRequestMessage in Minimal API NET 6?