# Web api HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get some of api users request information like the device that they use and the operating system so I tried it like this :

```
private string GetDeviceInfo()
    {
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
        var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
        var c = uaParser.Parse(userAgent);
        return c.Device + "|" + c.OS + "|" + c.UserAgent;
    }
```

but the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent` is always null !. I searched about it and tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364801/how-to-get-ipaddress-and-useragent-in-asp-net-web-api-get-methods) , could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? if so what values are in `userAgent` also take a look at this posting.. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42347/How-to-Detect-Browser-Capabilities-in-ASP-NET

Comment: may be your client is not sending the user-agent header. how are you accessing your api? @Figo

Comment: @DJKRAZE `userAgent` is `null` as the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent` is `null` it throws an exception of kind `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(String input) at UAParser.Parser.Parsers.||c_DisplayClass43`1.|Create|b41(String input)` !

Comment: @ZohaibAslam my client is calling the api directly `/api/request`, should I force the client to send these information ? if so how ?

Comment: try this site...http://www.yetanotherforum.net/forum/posts/t8877-Bug-Fixes-For-The-Bugs-I-ve-Found#post36155

Comment: yes @Figo, you have to, otherwise user-agent will be null, otherwise you can try some browser, it will automatically set headers. another option is fiddler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Request.UserAgent` is just value of ["user agent" header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in HTTP request. Browser will automatically send it with all requests (including AJAX), no-browser clients generally will not include such header.

If your "client" is not browser it needs to add the header with appropriate values itself.

Sample if using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
request.UserAgent="My custom user agent string";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Yes I tried to call my api with a console app and web browser, I got the difference , thank you for your answer.