# Asp.NET MVC REST API: How to get Client Host Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am developing REST API application in ASP.NET MVC3. I am trying to get client client HOST Name in action but cannot success. I am using this API in multiple applications so I want to log the domain name.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712720/get-web-api-consumer-ip-address-and-hostname-in-asp-net-web-api)

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571292/1558544)

```
private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
    {
        return ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    else if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
        prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
        return prop.Address;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

All these options providing IP address but i want to get host name

**API Controller**  www.myapi.com

```
public class TESTController : ApiController
{
    public TESTController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public object Add(string data = "")
    {
        try
        {
            string result = "0";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                //should be www.myapiconsume.com
                var host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
                var ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }

            return new { response = result };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

**Calling API Action from different domain** www.myapiconsume.com

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var url = "http://myapi.com/api/test/add?data={0}";
            url = string.Format(url, "{ data}");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString(url);
            return Content(result);
        }

    }
```

How can i get this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx) Method to reverse look up.

```
public static string ReverseLookup(string ip)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip))
        return ip;

    try
    {
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);

        return host != null ? host.HostName : ip;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        return ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no select method for Dns.GetHostEntry(ip). am i right?

Comment: strange thing it is displaying Server Hosting Space name. as cpp.blue.sitehosted.com. this function displaying the "blue".

Comment: DNS itself is a complex topic - forwarding, redirecting, internal, external. Once you publish to Production *(with public IP)*, it might be different compare to development machine *(with internal IP)*. However, looking up DNS based on IP address is not 100% reliable. My suggestion is your application not to rely on HostName.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supplied by default, unfortunately; if you're on the same network, you can try:

```
var result = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr"));
```

but that may also have issues if the client is coming through a proxy, etc.

Comment: It providing the server name but i want domain name. Both applications hosted on same server but different website

Answer (score 1):

Update the calling action:

```
var url = "http://myapi.com/api/test/add?data={0}";
url = string.Format(url, "{ data}");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Referer", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
var result = client.DownloadString(url);
return Content(result);
```

then on target server:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.Host
```

If your server has a public ip then you can try to resolve it:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress)
```

Comment: Nope,provided domain name where API is hosted but I want to get client domain name where i this API is using. My API is hosted on www.myapi.com and i am calling it from www.consumeapi.com

Comment: @AskQuestion do yo want to get www.consumeapi.com?

Comment: yes,  www.consumeapi.com should be in host varaible. I have update the question

Comment: Are you developing the client applications too?