# Can IP address for same user change within a user session in an ASP.Net app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the code below to get user's IP address in my ASP.Net application.

**Question** : Is it possible that the value of `userIPAddress` variable can change for the same user across requests within the same user session? I am assuming that a user could be accessing the ASP.Net app from either a laptop or a mobile device.

```
string userIPAddress =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: May be chnged if behind proxy server or in Intranet Environment using dynamic dhcp server. Review: https://thepcspy.com/read/getting_the_real_ip_of_your_users/  and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726576/system-web-httpcontext-current-request-userhostaddress
to get user ip address

Comment: Doesn't UserHostAddress get the IP address of the proxy server, so all users behind that proxy server would give the same UserHostAddress? I am not sure if proxy server have dynamic or static IP.

Comment: Ip address is the address of the Proxy server (which may be static/dynamic based on ISP service and his own router configuration),so all users behind the proxy server have same real IP address. Proxy server ,really, is Natting, it means ,mange user by giving every one private IP address which is not visible outside(but can be reached :) ).

Comment: @M.Hassan, Thanks for your informative comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of the user can change for various reasons, a new DHCP lease or just a manual change of a static IP address.

Because the ASP.Net session is just based on the session, the same session continues even if the user has a different `UserHostAddress`.

You can easily test this by establishing a session in you application and then manually change your static IP address. Your session stays intact.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. So it seems that the IP address using `UserHostAddress` is not reliable. I was trying to use IP address to decide in ASP.Net app whether a user had been impersonated by a hacker using another computer. But using IP address for this is never going to work due to its unreliability.

Comment: well it reliably shows the current address of the user, (or a proxy in between) but you are right it's not reliable to assume impersonation.

Comment: IP address obtained  in ASP.Net should be used purely for information purposes `only` and never for implementing business rules since its unreliable.

Comment: The first thing I thought why the IP address can change is because the device switches to another network. For instance, when a smartphone switches from mobile data to Wi-Fi or vice versa.

Comment: @hvd, And with technologies evolving so fast nowadays, one should never rely on IP address.

Comment: Brief and useful, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the real IP address for the user, it makes sense to check the value of this first:

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables[“HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR”]

If that value is empty or null, then check the UserHostAddress property.
the following code from the reference: http://jacobmsaylor.com/?p=1693

```
private string GetClientIPAddress()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_VIA"] != null)
        {
            // Let's first check for a proxy
            var ipAddresses = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(',');
            return ipAddresses[0].Trim();
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != null
            && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != string.Empty)
        {
            // If they are not using one
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        else
        {               
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: But it seems due to various security measures that are taken by internet service providers, even the method you gave is not reliable. I think any IP address obtained in ASP.Net is only for information purpose and should never be used to implement some business logic in an ASP.Net app.

Comment: Sure, it isn't reliable 100% , but may be used by some site to control e.g.download by user. So Cookies with authentication is used to identify user: who is he :)

Comment: X-Forwarded_For is controlled by the sender.  It's only trustworthy if you control the sender (e.g., if it's being set by a load balancer under which you control).

Comment: So, it seems that getting IP address in ASP.Net is unreliable.